# Xubuntu on Macmini, Would not boot, stupidly reset PRAM

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, uefi, apple

Xubuntu on Macmini, Would not boot, stupidly reset PRAM...

I Only have Linux partition on the HDD, im not really a Mac or OSX fanboy, But this makes a great HTPC! I have installed so much, and have sourcecode in there i dont want to loose. 
Now i can boot into a live cd, and copy mostly everything, but it would take me days to get it to the current state!

I had Refind on it, and it would boot Grub then Xubuntu!
What i need now is a way to fix grub2, i have tried several tutorials, Boot-repair etc.
I cant get anything to restore the EFI... its just a folder with a question mark on it!

Could anyone help me with a quick fix?

EFI partition is on sda1 and boot(grub) on sda2, linux is sda3(lvm) and theres a swap partition if im not mistaken.

Please help since im leaving it to my kids and really need to fix this asap.
It was such a nice setup,XBMC with a PS3Navi as its controller!

Ps: i cannot boot into OSX, its deleted from my hdd... and i have no DVDS to install it.
I have a drive with OSX on, that i can connect through usb, it has refit on it, which would be of great help, but its in another city!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Using any emergency disc you like (Linux or OS X), prepare a small *non-journaled* HFS+ partition. ("Small" = ~100MiB to 1GiB.) Chances are you'll need to shrink another partition to do this, of course. Backing up that partition is highly advisable.
2. Download the rEFInd binary `.zip` file and unpack it somewhere convenient (such as that HFS+ partition you've just created).
3. Boot from an OS X installation/emergency disc.
4. Once you get to the point where a menu bar is visible, use it to open a Terminal window.
5. Install rEFInd by running `install.sh` with its `--ownhfs` option, as in `sudo ./install.sh --ownhfs /dev/disk0s5`, changing `/dev/disk0s5` as necessary.
6. Reboot.

The result should be that rEFInd will appear and enable you to boot. It will also appear in a location that should cause the firmware to find it and present it in its menu when you hold down the Option key while booting, so you should be able to recover a little more easily in the future. Some caveats:

- The `--ownhfs` option to `install.sh` is new, so be sure to use rEFInd version 0.7.6 or later. (0.7.6 is current as I write.)
- When I've tested this method of booting, rEFInd has failed to scan some partitions. If this happens, hit the Esc key to have rEFInd re-scan for boot loaders. Uncommenting the `scan_delay` option overcomes this problem permanently. (Setting the value to `1` is probably adequate.)
- If rEFInd is reading your Linux kernels from a Linux filesystem, you'll need to either manually install the driver(s) or use the `--alldrivers` option to install all the drivers. If you do the latter, manually removing the drivers you don't need is advisable.

If you don't have an OS X emergency disc or if this procedure doesn't work, you could try installing it from Linux using the `--usedefault` option to install rEFInd to the ESP using the default/fallback filename, as in `sudo ./install.sh --usedefault /dev/sda1`. *Some* (but not all) Macs will boot from the default/fallback filename if they can't find another boot loader, so this may work well for you; but if your model doesn't use the default/fallback filename, this alternate procedure will fail.

Comment: Could i make a HFS partition on a USBstick or hdd and use that to boot up refit after using OSX DVD to bless the USB?? i hope i havent damaged the internal HDD partition trying to get it to boot..thank you so much for your reply, im gonna try with the USB rather than creating a new partition i have really bad experience with resizing GPT disks created by another os...

Comment: If you're willing to leave a USB flash drive permanently attached, then yes, you could do that; or you could try the rEFInd USB flash drive image, which is available on the [rEFInd downloads page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)

Comment: hmm yes thats an issue... but i could bless it with refind when im able to login to my xubuntu hdd, at least i think.

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried several things after the last comment. The easiest solution is often the best. I had problems, since my OSX Mountain Lion disk was scratched, and would not boot, and then i started to try to make HFS drives with Xubuntu on my laptop, i managed to do that, since it works with "normal" pcs to make a fat32 drive and stick the EFI folder to that! never the less.

Comment: IF YOU EVER HAVE THIS PROBLEM!

                  the solution is!! 

                       da dang! Drum roll!!

                     Refind Cd image! just burn that to a disk!
                     and voila!

I guess you could do a refind usb, but my Macmini just wont boot a USB that is not a OSX HDD(not install disk)

Now where do i mark this as solved!!

and once again thank you so much, had i only thought about this hours ago!!! from now on this is the standard, no more booting up from a OSX HDD, i can just format it! YOSH!